Spring Boot app is not accessible via localhost:8080
I am going through this tutorial
https://learnk8s.io/spring-boot-kubernetes-guide
I am at the part when you install mongodb and the app is running. But I cannot access it via localhost:8080 its a Whitelabel Error Page. What kind of configuration I might miss?

So what have you tried? What have you confirmed to work? have you opened a terminal in the container and verified that the spring boot app IS running? maybe with curl? If so, have you got anything else running on port 8080? have you verified that setup? is there a vhost setup requiring a different hostname than localhost? please [edit] your question and add more information.

The tutorial is for Spring Boot 2.1 (and is over 5 years old) I suspect you tried it with Spring Boot 3.3 and it isn't working (because it is written for 10 versions before). Find a proper up-to-date tutorial instead.
